# SQL Syntax Highlighting not working

Tags: visual-studio-2012, syntax-highlighting

When I open *.sql file with Visual Studio 2012 Update 3, I'm not getting sql syntax highlighting, all text is in white (dark theme is used). I remember I was testing some RedGate SQL addons but all of this is uninstalled now. I'm sure Visual Studio reinstallation will solve this, but is there maybe an easier solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved problem by reinstalling SQL Server Data Tools from here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx